# Why client_updated_time of OneDrive folder does not match with DateModified

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, onedrive

I have a folder in local disk which gets uploaded to OneDrive (this is done in Windows store app).
In download operation I try to get client_updated_time for the OneDrive uploaded folder.
When I compare it with the local folder DateModified, it doesn't match.

Value A:
client_updated_time
{6/26/2014 11:06:25 AM} got from by using Convert.ToDateTime on -> 
{[client_updated_time, 2014-06-26T18:06:25+0000]}

Value B:
Local folder (StorageFolder) update time
{6/26/2014 11:05:51 AM -07:00}

Value C:
Local folder (StorageFolder) create time
{6/26/2014 11:04:25 AM -07:00}

As per description of field client_updated_time, I suppose value A and B are supposed to match. Why are the different?
Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing the client_updated_time when making the upload to OneDrive? If it's not provided its value will either remain as-is (if it's an update), or be the same value as the creation time (if it's a create).

Comment: oh. I missed that.
Let me try sending that value and I will post results back.

Thank you.

Comment: nope. Still doesn't work.
I even tried giving some fixed value (e.g. 6/27/2014 11:13:56 AM)
But when I read from client_updated_time it gives it's own time :(
like the one I mentioned in my question

So I tried using 
"description"
for storing my updated date and then read from that field. It's a workaround.

Comment: Sorry, this was my bad. The "client_updated_time" doesn't appear to be writable, which means there's no way that I'm aware of a client to control those values. Hopefully this restriction is lifted in the future.